# Redirect with full URL with condition in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to add redirection code for HTTPS in the .htacess file so it redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS. My goal is to Archive:

1. redirect "http://berryman.com" to 'https://berryman.com"
2. redirect "http://berryman.com/mls" to
   'https://berryman.com/mls"
   Here is the code that I'm using for that

   ```
   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   #Inorder to access object1
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   #Inorder to access object2
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portal
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)berryman\.com [NC]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://berryman.com/$1 [R,L]
   ```

this works fine for the first condition, but I can't able to achieve the second condition. Every time I use berryman.com/mls it's add  berryman.com/index.php behind it and shows 404 Page Not Found error.

Comment: Do you have some other rule also working in same htaccess or in other directory?

Comment: yes there are some other rules in that same .htaccess

Comment: Move your last rule to the top of your .htaccess

Comment: yeah... that works for me. thank you!